# Codeigniter select single row from table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I have a table named `news` in my database and, using querybuilder, I want to obtain only the news with a specific `id`. I wrote this code but in the view I got no result.

```
$this->db->from("news");
$q=$this->db->get_where('news', array('id' => $idNotizia));
$data['notizie'] =$q->result_array();
```

If i print the numrow() method of the query I can see that there is a row but if I run this for there is no text

```
foreach($notizie as $notizia)
{
    echo $notizia["titoloit"];
}
```

Comment: can you add properly what you have done in model ,view and controller as you are using codeigniter

Comment: Sorry, the first part is made in the controller and the second in the view, where i passed the data array in which is contained the variable 'notizie'

Comment: what is result of `print_r($notize)` in view

Comment: I can see the spelling mistake in view file. Query result has been assigned in $data['notize'] variable and you are using $notizie in your foreach loop. Please cross check and let us know if it is working or not.

Comment: Sorry it's a type mistake in the question. I fix now.(the code doesn't work and I obtain the error Not unique table/alias: 'news')

Comment: for single row you can use row_array() instead of result_array()

Answer (score 1):

Oh this question has lasted so long.
From the comment I can see the error is actually

> Error Number: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'news' SELECT * FROM news, news WHERE id = '1' Filename: controllers/News.php

The error was from the database. Look at the generated query `SELECT * FROM news, news`: there are two "news", which makes the database confused. Try remove the first line.

```
// $this->db->from("news"); No you dont need this with get_where
$q=$this->db->get_where('news', array('id' => $idNotizia));
$data['notize'] =$q->result_array();

$notizie = $q->result_array();
if($q->num_rows()>0){
  foreach($notizie as $notizia)
  {
     echo $notizie["titoloit"];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->from("news");
$q=$this->db->get_where('news', array('id' => $idNotizia));
$data['notize'] =$q->result_array();

$notizie = $q->result_array();
if($q->num_rows()>0){
  foreach($notizie as $notizia)
  {
     echo $notizie["titoloit"];
  }
}
```

this should work. In your pasted code the variable inside foreach is $notizia, which I guess you mean $notizie right?

Comment: It's the same code written by me. It doesn't work. No I mean $notizia like the manual explain
http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Answer (score 0):

Model

```
$this->db->from("news");
$q=$this->db->get_where('news', array('id' => $idNotizia));
$data['notize'] =$q->result_array();
$this->load->view('your_viewFIleName' , $data);
```

you should pass your data to the view controller

Comment: I did it before but I obtained this error
Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'news'

SELECT * FROM `news`, `news` WHERE `id` = '1'

Filename: controllers/News.php